# What is the Quran and Sunnah view on Nepotism?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, sunnah

I can only find one thing online, but I am not sure of it's validity as I can't find it on any of the traditional sunni reputable websites.

> Abdul Malik ibn ‘Umayr reported: Umar ibn al-Khattab, may Allah be pleased with him, said, “Whoever employs a man among his loved ones or relatives, employing him for no other reason besides that, then he has betrayed Allah, His messenger, and the believers.”

> عن عبد الملك بن عُمَير قال قال عمرُ بن الخطاب رضي الله عنه مَن اسْتعملَ رجلاً لِمَوَدَّة أو لِقَرابَةٍ لا يستعمِلُه إلاَّ لذلك فقد خانَ اللَّهَ وَرَسُولَهُ والمؤمِنينَ

Source: [(Musnad al-Fārūq 740)](https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2019/08/14/umar-nepotism-betrayal-islam/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nepotism is obviously haram when it leads to other haram things such as injustice or giving guardianship over public interests to those who are incompetent or corrupt hence causing harm. There can be several relevant texts such as the following:

> يا أيها الذين آمنوا كونوا قوامين بالقسط شهداء لله ولو على أنفسكم أو الوالدين والأقربين إن يكن غنيا أو فقيرا فالله أولى بهما فلا تتبعوا الهوى أن تعدلوا وإن تلووا أو تعرضوا فإن الله كان بما تعملون خبيرا
>
> O you who have believed, be persistently standing firm in justice, witnesses for Allah, even if it be against yourselves or parents and relatives. Whether one is rich or poor, Allah is more worthy of both. So follow not [personal] inclination, lest you not be just. And if you distort [your testimony] or refuse [to give it], then indeed Allah is ever, with what you do, Acquainted.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:135](https://quran.com/4/135?translations=20)</sup>

> إن بني إسرائيل كان إذا سرق فيهم الشريف تركوه، وإذا سرق الضعيف قطعوه، لو كانت فاطمة لقطعت يدها
>
> If a reputable man amongst the children of Bani Israel committed a theft, they used to forgive him, but if a poor man committed a theft, they would cut his hand. But I would cut even the hand of Fatima (i.e. the daughter of the Prophet ﷺ) if she committed a theft.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3733)</sup>

And it is also evident from more general texts such as:

> إن الله يأمركم أن تؤدوا الأمانات إلى أهلها وإذا حكمتم بين الناس أن تحكموا بالعدل
>
> Indeed, Allah commands you to render trusts to whom they are due and when you judge between people to judge with justice.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:58](https://quran.com/4/58?translations=20)</sup>

> ما من عبد استرعاه الله رعية، فلم يحطها بنصيحة، إلا لم يجد رائحة الجنة
>
> Any man whom Allah has given the authority of ruling some people and he does not look after them in an honest manner, will never feel even the smell of Paradise.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7150)</sup>

> إذا أسند الأمر إلى غير أهله، فانتظر الساعة
>
> When authority is given to those who do not deserve it, then wait for the Hour.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6496)</sup>

Because Nepotism involves giving positions without regard to ability.

As for the athar of Umar which you have quoted, it is disconnected as  Abdul Malik ibn Umair  did not meet Umar. Also keep in mind that Umar is talking about public offices such as governors and tax collectors and not about private employment. The ahadith in [Mu'jam al-Kabir Tabarani](https://shamela.ws/book/1733/13263)  or [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/7830) are also related although they have weakness.